# How to break an image out of bootstrap container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, image, containers, breakout

I am trying to break an image out of bootstrap container, here is my code,

```
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
                    <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    <img class="break-img" src="img-src">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to achieve something like this. But in the markup the image must be inside the container-row-col structure. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put the image inside all of those elements. You can use `container-fluid` for example with additional classes if necessarily:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
            <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="something" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :( is there any CSS rule by which I can achieve this, without creating a new "container/container-fluid"? Thank You.

Comment: Maybe there is a CSS hack (I'm not so sure about that), but that would be a bad solution, I think, because the image doesn't belong to the `container`, if it doesn't respect the `container`'s width.